# In Oracle's eTRM tool, what is the difference between these 2 "Table" sections /

Tags: oracle

I'm studying oracle e-business suite material, including looking through eTRM. Well in there I find the AR directory(terminology?). and I see this page:

[image]

I'm a bit confused about what's shown here. for example, what is the difference between "Table" under the Apps heading, and "Table" under "AR" heading?

If this is off-top. , is there a Stackexchange site for this kind of material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing two different `schemas`. Each of then has their own objects. The difference is that the `APPS` schema has more tables than the `AR` schema. Also, the arrows point to `SYNONYM` and for `SEQUENCE`

A `SYNONYM` is an object that oracle use as some kind of alias for objects.

A `SEQUENCE` is kind of autoincrement object used for fields of tables. There is no direct link between a table field and a sequence you create then and use then at your wheel